# Using SDL-C library with Code::Blocks on Windows...wizard can't locate SDLmain library file

Tags: windows, sdl, codeblocks, libraries, wizard

I am new to programming and I am trying to use SDL library with Code::Blocks on Windows. I downloaded the Library from : https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php.
I downloaded the files, decompressed and then copied `SDL.dll` file in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`

and then the `include` and `lib` files in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL`,

which is a new file I created. However, when I open Code::Blocks, new SDL project and arrive at the step where I am supposed to give the directory where the include and lib files are, once I hit next I get the following error :

```
The path you entered seems valid but the wizard can't locate the following SDL's library file: SDLmain in it.
```

Any idea why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you gone through all the steps laid out here? http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/

Comment: I tried using an earlier version of SDL and it worked, so I guess the version of Code::Blocks I had ( I think 10.05 ) didn't support SDL2. I changed this and it worked, thanks anyway @SerkanPekçetin